# provide all solutions of $dy-y\,dx=0$ and $\int f(x)\;dx = f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$e^x$ is the solution of both equations . the differential operator and integration operator has no effect on $e^x$. So, is there any other function that possesses this property . Or is $e^x$ unique in this regard ?

Comment: Unique up to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

For $dy = y\ dx$,
if $y(x_0)=0$,
then $dy(x_0) = 0$,
and, by repeated differentiation,
$d^{(n)}y(x_0) = 0$ for all $n$,
so $y(x) = 0$ identically.

So, we can assume that
$y(x) \ne 0$.
We can then write
$\frac{dy}{y} = dx$
or $(\ln(y))' = dx$.
Integrating,
$\ln(y) = x+c$
or $y = Ce^x$,
where $C = e^c$.

The other is easier,
so I'll leave it for others to get the points.

Comment: This is not quite complete.  The number $e^c$ is necessarily positive.  But if $C\le 0$, one still has a valid solution.  The problems are (1) you have $\ln y$ where $\ln|y|$ is appropriate, and (2) $dy/y$ makes sense ONLY when $y\ne 0$, so you have to check $y=0$ separately.